# Pythonでsendgridをつかいたいのですが

Tags: python

sendgrid.SendGridClient(api_user,api_key)がサンプルにあったので、デプロイしてみたのですが、

```
# using SendGrid's Python Library - https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(X6En2mtgiK, 1-mJrsgsS9ewCaQUP_xCgw)
message = sendgrid.Mail()
```

ログには、とでて、api_usrに入れるのに何をいれればいいのかわかりません。
教えてください

```
 File "server.py", line 23, in <module>
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient(X6En2mtgiK, 1-mJrsgsS9ewCaQUP_xCgw)
NameError: name 'X6En2mtgiK' is not defined
```

Comment: 文字列は''か""でくくりましょう。シンタックスエラーですので、設定以前の問題です。